# VS Code- Flutter/dart code is not recognised and cannot run the main function from VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have an issue where VS Code is not recognizing my Flutter/Dart code. No run over Main function. No suggestions when I hit (ctrl + period) No error detection
[image: VS Code Screenshot]

However when I hit flutter run from the command line it works properly and the flutter doctor command it shows no problems
[image: flutter doctor]

I have tried the following

1. removing dart and flutter vs code extensions and installing them again
2. reinstalling vs code
3. clearing cache from flutter/bin and reinstall using `flutter pub cache repair`

But without any solving to the problem

Comment: did you install flutter extension in VS Code?